# Rails Polymorphic Associations Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I have

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :products, :as => :imageable
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :store
  has_many :products, :as => imageable
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

and I migrated:

```
class AddImageableToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :products do |t|
      t.references :imageable, :polymorphic => true
    end
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :products, :imageable
  end
end
```

When I try to run my app I get: undefined local variable or method `imageable'
and I don't know what I have missing to have  this run. Id appreciate it if somebody could help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @kishie, since Product is Polymorphic, it can be associated with more than one models, you need to have two columns in products table to identify the model this is instance is associated with. `imageable_id` and `imageable_type`.

I am sure you have this in you lib folder.

```
lib/imageable.rb
module Imageable
    def self.included(base)
        base.class_eval do
            has_many :products, :as => imageable
        end
    end
end
```

Since, I am assuming you're using Rails 3, the contents of lib folder are not loaded automatically. You should have this in your `application.rb`

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Add fields, migrate, edit application.rb and you're set with polymorphic associations.

Comment: Thanks Sam. I am using Rails 3 and I wasn't aware that there needed to be a separate lib file or have config.autoload_paths in application.rb. I read about polymorphic associations on rubyonrails.org and it didn't mention any of that. Do you know where I can read about what you suggested to me? Thanks a bunch

Comment: I tried everything you mentioned, and I am still getting the same error. Is polymorphic association supposed to be this complicated to implement?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, in your case you should use something like "productable".
But if you anyway want to use this name you should add to your products table thwe following fields:

`imageable_id` as integer and `imageable_type` as string.

And one more thing, in your migration you can use this

```
def self.up
 add_column :table_name, :field_name, :field_type
end

def self.down
 remove_column :table_name, :field_name
end
```

instead of your code =)

Comment: Thank you Kishie. I tried to do it with productable and changed to imageable just to see if that'd make a difference. Since I am new to rails I just try to stay as close to the guide as possible :) Thanks for the suggestion